# Por que razon los botones en un xml en android studio no me deja cambiarlos de color?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

Buenas tardes a todos los miembros de este mundo, me encuentro en un problema y creo que nadie a preguntado por que razon...

Resulta que a la hora de cambiar el color de uno de los botones a X Y Z color solo queda en el color colorPrimary y al cambiar el nombre del color, cambian a un rosado (segunda imagen evidencia), y nose como hacer para que cada uno tenga un color personalizado sin necesidad de dañar los demas botones.

[image: imagen normal]

[image: Imagen 2 del XML]
[image: Imagen 2]

Este es mi archivo `colors.xml` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier persona que sepa solucionarlo seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te aconsejo definir un color que sea exclusivo para los botones que deseas, realizalo dentro de `colors.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    ...
    ...
    ...
    <color name="color_purple">#2A2A2A</color>

</resources>
```

y lo defines en los botones que desees de esta forma:

```
<Button
    android:background="@color/color_purple"
     ../>
```

o de esta forma:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_purple"
     ../>
```